# Is there a way to calculate average for a previous column condition?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, mean

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
Date-Time      Diff        Load    Load_number
10/22/2019     -386                  0                
10/23/2019     -380                  0                 
10/24/2019     -370                  0                
10/25/2019     5000        Yes       1              
10/26/2019     -490                  1             
10/27/2019     -480                  1             
10/28/2019     -470                  1             
10/22/2019     5000        Yes       2              
10/23/2019     -380                  2              
10/24/2019     -370                  2              
10/25/2019     5000        Yes       3              
10/26/2019     -490                  3              
10/27/2019     5800        Yes       4                 
10/28/2019     -550                  4                 
10/29/2019     -500                  4
```

Can someone help me find the absolute average of previous load number?

The output would look something like this:

```
Date-Time      Diff        Load    Load_number     Average
10/22/2019     -386                  0                0
10/23/2019     -380                  0                0    
10/24/2019     -370                  0                0
10/25/2019     5000        Yes       1              378.66
10/26/2019     -490                  1              378.66
10/27/2019     -480                  1              378.66
10/28/2019     -470                  1              378.66
10/22/2019     5000        Yes       2               480
10/23/2019     -380                  2               480
10/24/2019     -370                  2               480
10/25/2019     5000        Yes       3               375
10/26/2019     -490                  3               375
10/27/2019     5800        Yes       4               490   
10/28/2019     -550                  4               490   
10/29/2019     -500                  4               490
```

Here, when `Load_number = 1`, the average column will have an absolute difference value of previous `Load_number`. When finding average, we do not consider the positive values (e.g. Diff 5000).

Comment: Is `load_number` guaranteed to always be consecutive?

Comment: @BrianJoseph Yes it does

Comment: @AmoghKatwe check my answer should be good

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
load_averages = df.groupby('Load_number')['Diff'].agg(lambda s: s[s <= 0].mean()).shift(1).fillna(0).abs().to_dict()
df['Average'] = df['Load_number'].map(load_averages)

>>> df

    Date-Time   Diff    Load_number Load    Average
0   10/22/2019  -386.0      0.0             0.0
1   10/23/2019  -380.0      0.0             0.0
2   10/24/2019  -370.0      0.0             0.0
3   10/25/2019  5000.0      1.0     Yes     378.6666666666667
4   10/26/2019  -490.0      1.0             378.6666666666667
5   10/27/2019  -480.0      1.0             378.6666666666667
6   10/28/2019  -470.0      1.0             378.6666666666667
7   10/22/2019  5000.0      2.0     Yes     480.0
8   10/23/2019  -380.0      2.0             480.0
9   10/24/2019  -370.0      2.0             480.0
10  10/25/2019  5000.0      3.0     Yes     375.0
11  10/26/2019  -490.0      3.0             375.0
12  10/27/2019  5800.0      4.0     Yes     490.0
13  10/28/2019  -550.0      4.0             490.0
14  10/29/2019  -500.0      4.0             490.0
```

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```py
averages = df[df['Diff']<=0].groupby('Load_number')['Diff'].mean()
averages.loc[-1] = 0
df['Average'] = df.apply(lambda row: averages.loc[row.Load_number-1], axis=1)
```

Comment: This does not ignore the positive values

Comment: @AmoghKatwe I edited it with that fix around 17 mins ago, check again